# Marker with label does not appear

Tags: google-maps-api-3, label, markers

I want to attach labels to my markers, using the markerwithlabel.js package (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/). I put the package link in the document header, and added the label properties in my addMarker function. I have no idea why the labels do not appear, since before I added the label properties everything worked. Am I missing something?

In the header:

```
        <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here I create the markers:

```
//iterate through marker data and assign values to variables
            for (i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i][1], markerData[i][2]);
                var title = markerData[i][0];
                var category = markerData[i][3];
                var new_marker = addMarker(pos, title, category);
                arrMarkers.push(new_marker);
                new_marker.setVisible(false);
            }

            //create marker based on the variables
            function addMarker (pos, title, category) {
                var marker = new google.maps.MarkerWithLabel({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    icon: "mapIcons/marker_"+markerData[i][4]+".png",
                    category: category,
                    labelContent: "test",
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},


                });  

                infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
                    shadowStyle: 1
                });

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 
                var info = 'Functie: ' + '<b>' + markerData[i][0] + "</b>" + '<br>' + 'Eigenschappen: ' + '<b>' + markerData[i][6] + "</b>" ;  //html inside InfoWindow 
                //var video = "<div>" + '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4gMH0V4L4A4">' + '</iframe>' + "</div>";  //html inside InfoWindow
                var video = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="250" height="188" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UmFjNiiVk9w?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
                //var video = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="200" height="180" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4gMH0V4L4A4?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
                //var video = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/S_9CSFeO9sM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
                var media = "<b>" + 'Laatste foto, ontvangen op 15:33 9-7-2013' + "</b>" + '<img src="others/schiphol_marechaussee.jpg" alt="laatste foto">'  ;  //html inside InfoWindow 
                var contact = ' <form><textarea rows="10" cols="30">Typ hier je bericht</textarea>' + '<input type="reset" value="Verstuur"></form>';  //html inside InfoWindow 


                if (markerData[i][5] == 'info') {
                    bindInfoWindowInfo(marker, map, infoBubble, info);
                    infoBubble.addTab('Info', info);
                    infoBubble.addTab('Contact', contact);
                    infoBubble.addTab('Media', media);
                };
                if (markerData[i][5] == 'video') {
                    bindInfoWindowVideo(marker, map, infoBubble, video); 
                    infoBubble.addTab('Video', video);
                };


                return marker;
            }
```

Upon clicking a checkbox, the markers appear (that's why its setVisible is false).

Comment: What browsers have you tested in? Are you using an old version of IE to test it?  You have a "hanging comma" in your posted code.

Comment: The markers without label worked in Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: The "hanging comma" breaks older versions of IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code I get this error in the javascript console:

> Error: google.maps.MarkerWithLabel is not a constructor

because MarkerWithLabel is not part of the Google Maps API v3.  Change the constructor to:

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                map: map,
                ...
```

[working example (at least the MarkerWithLabel is working)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_MarkerWithLabel.html)

Comment: Spot on! That did the trick. Extra question; what is an easy way to get the error output of the code? Would give me some extra info regarding what is going wrong? Run the code in the console i guess? Do i need some extra log statement or something? Anyway, many thanks for this already!

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J (Firefox,Chrome), F12 in IE or look in the menus under Tools.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna use that a lot i guess ;)

Comment: Hi I am still getting Error: google.maps.MarkerWithLabel is not a constructor.

Comment: Sound like you didn't understand the answer.  In any case that should be a new question, with a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue and shows how you are including the MarkerWithLabel library (i.e. why you believe it is a different question).